# CVS commit doesn't work and doesn't give any feedback

Tags: cvs

I am facing an issue with CVS that I am trying to do a CVS commit, but for some reason I am getting nothing back. I have checked the files and the commit message and I see no issues there, so what could be the issue that I am not getting anything back? I have pinged the repository server without any problems, so it is not a network issue.

Comment: Post what client and what commands are you using. Also, check if other operations on the repository work as expected.

Comment: This is the command:
cvs -f commit -F "./keeptemps/commit-log.20210309.004411" applied.patches

and I am using cvs in the commad prompt, nit smart cvs or anything like that